# URL changes in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I think my routing may have an issue. When I submit a form with errors, my URL changes.

So, the URL starts off as this: http://localhost:3000/user_profile/edit

I then submit the form with an error:

[image: The I submit the form with an error]

And now the URL is this: http://localhost:3000/user_profile.17

Controller:

```
def update
    @user_profile = current_user.user_profile
    if @user_profile.update_attributes(user_profile_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      if params[:user_profile][:procedure_ids] == nil
        redirect_to user_dashboards_show_path
      # If competencies were modified, redirect to competency details
      else
        redirect_to edit_competency_details_path
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
resource :user_profile
```

Comment: Try `resources :user_profile`

Comment: This is a singular resource though. I just noticed that the question was asked here as well, but not answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475380/why-does-the-render-method-change-the-path-for-a-singular-resource-after-an-edit

Comment: show your view codes